# Image still shown correctly(?) when retina version removed

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, I have `UITabBarController`. It has say one `ViewController`, which also has a TabBar item set with an image. When I run the program on simulator for iPhone, the image is shown ok. Then I decided to test it, and removed the @2x version of the same image - and switched to a iPhone (Retina 4 inch) during simulating, in Hardware->Device menu, but the image is still shown OK. Why is it, can someone explain?

Comment: Uninstall the application from the emulator, sometimes it does not remove the files that you removed from the project and they stay until you uninstall/remove the application from the device or the emulator.

Comment: @Anton: How do I do that Uninstall? Actually, when I switched to Retina device in Hardware menu, my app got "minimized" it dissapeared, then I had to relaunch it from inside the simulator. Guess it was kind of installed there?

Comment: the same way you uninstall from the real device, in the menu hold the mouse down over the icon for several seconds and the delete button will appear.
Also I had instances when I had to cleanup the project for the old files to be cleaned up. In the menu of xcode you can try Product->Clean

Comment: @Anton: Ok, I uninstalled it, and it seems I see the difference now, the image is a bit blurred.

Answer (score 1):

Clean the app and remove it from the device, this has happened to me several times.

Anyway, what's the problem on having both images at the same time? the system will choose the proper one.

Comment: "Anyway, what's the problem on having both images at the same time? the system will choose the proper one.". No, it's ok, i am doing it just for learning purposes. btw. I have simulator, trying to follow Antons' advice now...

Comment: Ok, just remove the app before intalling, it hapened to me too

Answer (score 1):

Deploying to the Simulator does not remove old files, only add/replace files. Your Retina image is still there. You can remove it by resetting the Simulator.

This is not true of apps installed via the App Store on user devices.